# Is it interesting to consider satisfiability modulo theory in the context of modal logic?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

Recently lot of work has been done considering satisfiability of formulas in 
specific theory (array theory, bit-vector theory).
But I did not find any results about satisfiability modulo theory in the context
of modal logic ? 
Is there any reasons ? Is it useful to consider modal logic and satisfiability modulo theory ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

we have been working on SMT for modal logics, and we managed to prove that SMT with quantification yields a decision procedure for the basic modal logic (BML). This is not hard to prove when you work with the standard translation of the BML and common instanciation rules available in some SMT solvers. We also have the same results for other operators (inverse operator, graded operator). Ultimately our goal is to prove that SMT yields a decision procedure for the entire guarded fragment, which we guess that it is the case, but so far we didn't came up with satisfactory proof. In terms of efficiency, we are currently running some tests to see how an SMT prover does with modal formulas. So far, I don't have the numbers.

Comment: Well, when you say you proved that SMT with quantification yields a decision procedure for BML, which theory are you considering ? Array Theory ? Bit-Vector Theory ? To be sure, so far you found a decision procedure for formulae of some specific theory considering modal logic ?
Do you know the complexity of the procedure ? Lasdt , Do you have the reference of the paper ?
Many thanks.

Comment: We use SMT + Quantification + Uninterpreted Functions Theory. What we have done, is translate modal formulas to smt2 format using the standard translation. Then we feed them to the SMT solver. Some preliminary results, shows that for heavily propositional formulas, e.g., QBF formulas translated to BML, SMT outperforms a modal tableaux prover. We are running more tests to confirm this.

With respect to the paper, this still is unplished work, so I have no paper to send to you, we just have some notes, and proofs. Let me think how can I facilitate a copy.

Comment: Many thanks, I will be very happy to read some results about modal logic and SMT. There exists plenty of results about decision procedure for SMT and array theory, I was wondering if it could be interesting to extend those results considering modal logic  ...